# Group member dropdown in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

in visual studio is the member dropdown, where you can select all members of the current type alphabetically ordered.

is there an option which allows grouping of the members? i.e. all constructors before all methods before all properties before all events before all fields?

if there is not, bad for me, i guess — it would really enhance productivity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think VS supports this. You have to use an add-on. I use Resharper. Check out [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/), a free add-on.